# Textbox line number with enter key press

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to implement a **text insertion field which should automatically number each row** (based on the row break).

The user should not be able to choose this by themselves or remove the numbers, the text field should from the beginning be configured as a numbered list.

This is done in JQuery and I have not been able to find a solution.

Below is what I have tried but it does not work as it needs to.
I got solution from [LineAreaText Demo](http://files.aw20.net/jquery-linedtextarea/jquery-linedtextarea.html).

also [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/jMZKz/)

But need the structure as jsfiddle textbox like:

---

```
1. here is first line.
2. when press enter key this two will add in this line and 
   now I am not pressing enter key so there is no next line 
   count.
3. Now pressed enter and third is there as line number.
```

---

I have tried as

- Use editable div structure as above described but failed to put blank 
   when no enter key pressed and sentence is yet not completed.
- Use ajax htmleditor extender, But there is need to press orderred list icon button on top.

Here is what JsFiddle using same as i needed to do.

[image]

I would very much appreciate any help or guidance in this since I am stuck now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few lines of JavaScript will do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/mkWhy/1/  You just handle the onkeyup event of the textarea, split the current text into lines (split on the new line character '\n'), loop through those lines and make sure the beginning of each line has the correct number.

```
<textarea id="num" rows="5" cols="32">1. </textarea>
```

Plain JS

```
document.getElementById("num").onkeyup = function(e) {
    var evt = e ? e : event;
    if((evt.keyCode && evt.keyCode != 13) || evt.which != 13) 
        return;
    var elm = evt.target ? evt.target : evt.srcElement;
    var lines = elm.value.split("\n");
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/(\d+\.\s|^)/, (i+1) + ". ");
    elm.value = lines.join("\n");
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#num").keyup(function(event) {
    if(event.which != 13)
        return;
    var elm = $(this);
    var lines = elm.val().split("\n");
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/(\d+\.\s|^)/, (i+1) + ". ");
    elm.val(lines.join("\n"));
});
```

**EDIT** This is more inline with the OP's question, a jsfiddle type numbered text input. http://jsfiddle.net/qZqX8/

I use two textarea's have the first set to readonly and have them blot next to eachother. Then use the keyup and the scroll events on the input textarea. To keep the height and scroll position synchronized.

```
$(".numbered").scroll(function(event) {
    $(this).prev().height($(this).height());
    $(this).prev()[0].scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
});
$(".numbered").keyup(function(event) {
    var elm = $(this);
    var lines = elm.val().split("\n");
    var numbers = "";
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
        numbers += (i+1) + "\n";
    elm.prev().val(numbers);
    elm.prev()[0].scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
});
```

**EDIT 2** Here's a version that's similar to JSFiddle.net 's editor. I don't handle the text highlighting, shift, or arrow keys, but enter and backspace work. http://jsfiddle.net/gqHgb/

HTML

```
<div id="ref_line" style="display:none">
    <div class="line"><div class="lineno"></div><pre contenteditable="true"> </pre></div>
</div>
<div class="editor">
</div>
```

CSS I'm using the CSS counter() to handle line numbering

```
.editor {
    margin-left: 2em;
    counter-reset: lnno;
}
.editor .line {
    poisition: relative;
}
.line .lineno {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 2em;
    color: blue;
    text-align: right;
}
.line .lineno:before {
    counter-increment: lnno;
    content: counter(lnno);
}
.line pre {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

JS jQuery

```
// setup editors
$(".editor").each(function() {
    $(this).append($("#ref_line").html());
});
// line focus / blur
$(".editor").on("focus", ".line pre", function() {
    var pre = $(this);
    if(pre.text() == " ")
        pre.text("");
});
$(".editor").on("blur", ".line pre", function() {
    var pre = $(this);
    if(pre.text() == "")
        pre.text(" ");
});
// line add / remove
$(".editor").on("keydown", ".line pre", function(event) {
    var pre = $(this);
    if(event.which == 13) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        pre.parent().after($("#ref_line").html());
        pre.blur();
        pre.parent().next().find("pre").focus();
    } else if(event.which == 8 && pre.text() == "" && this != pre.parents(".editor").find("pre:first")[0]) {
        var back = pre.parent().prev();
        pre.parent().remove();
        back.find("pre").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @LastCoder. but the line number should not be deleted. can we use a div for number to display.

Comment: Actually the first one is much better need only no deletion of number. I have implemented the your new idea earlier but was stuck at same position that the number should follow its exact row. if i continue to write there be gap between next number.

Comment: @Janty - I don't understand what you mean by "if i continue to write there be gap between next number". When you say you don't want to delete row numbers do you mean that once a new line is created you don't want that line to every be removed? In any case I hope I got you at least part way there, good luck.

Comment: Have you seen Fiddle's textarea where we write our javascript, css and html code. I need to implement same functionality. There is a line number when pressed enter key, automaticly incremented and there will be vertical gap(empty ) between if line is too large and no enter key pressed .

Comment: @Janty - Yes Janty I understand now. that type of customization is quite a lot of work. You'd be better off searching for it, like a jQuery plugin that would do the job or some other pre-made widget. If you want to try making it on your own you'll need to handle a lot of keyboard input and use contenteditable.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.andrewmpeters.com/blog/how-to-detect-enter-keypress-with-javascript/

Will this be of any help?

It's about firing a function whenever a key is pressed.
So you probably just need a function that breaks a line and adds the last number with 1.

```
+=1
```

Javascript isn't my best language so this is all I could do.
I hope I sent you the right way.